# How to trim all the whitespace in hash's key?

Tags: ruby

Here's a hash:

```
hash = {"<start>"=>[["<intro>"]],
        "<intro> "=>[["<FirstSentence>", "<Funnel>", "<Thesis>"]],
        "<FirstSentence> "=>[["<StartingClause>", "<Group>", "<PastAction>", "."], ["<Quotation>", "--", "<Author>", "<QuoteEnd>", "<QuoteTransition>", "."]]}
```

`key[1]` and `key[2]` here have a white space after `>`. I want to delete that. I tried `tr(' ', '')`, `delete(' ')`, `strip`,`gsub`, etc.

```
hash.each do |key, _|
  key.delete(' ')
end
```

But they do not work. White space is immune to all the trimming/deleting methods. Am I using the method in a wrong way?

Comment: You may have to rebuild the hash e.g. `p hash.keys.map(&:strip).zip(hash.values).to_h`. Not sure if you can easily re-key the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hash.map { |k, v| [k.strip, v] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 2):

```
hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k.strip] = v }
  #=> {"<start>"=>[["<intro>"]],
  #    "<intro>"=>[["<FirstSentence>", "<Funnel>", "<Thesis>"]], 
  #    "<FirstSentence>"=>[["<StartingClause>", "<Group>", "<PastAction>", "."],
  #                        ["<Quotation>", "--", "<Author>", "<QuoteEnd>",
  #                         "<QuoteTransition>", "."]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop you are using wont work because your code is essentially deleting the whitespace from the variable `key` and not the hash itself.

What I would do is write a function that encapsulates the looping logic and returns a new hash with the keys modified, like this:

```
def normalize_keys!(hash)   
  buffer = {}
  hash.each do |key, value|
    buffer[key.strip] = value
  end   
  buffer
end

new_hash = normalize_keys!(old_hash)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method to apply is `delete!`, not `delete`. String#delete does not modify the receiver. String#delete! does.